# Mafia 3 no more damage to be dealt barclay mills

Tags: mafia-3

I did most of the barclay mills missions and brought the damage down to 2550 but now I can find anything else to damage or steal, so the meter is stuck at 2550 and the objective says "find and destroy garbage barges" but when I click it, no waypoint.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to barcleys mill area. Look for it on the map. Drive around and use your instict you'll see some enemies, kill them. Done.

Comment: I've done this for about half an hour and couldn't find anything. I'll try a while longer.

Answer (score -1):

I had and fixed the same problem as you. All you need to do is just find enemies around the map and kill them. This will decrease the required money for damage. Hope this helped.

Comment: any ideas where to find them?