# I can't take over barclay mills

Tags: mafia-3

I've done all the objectives in Barclay Mills, but it only took the damage scale down to $2550.  I've scoured the map for leftover objectives but no dice.  People tell me to find some enemies in Barclay Mills to kill, but I can't find them.

Comment: Please don't [re-ask](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/287669/mafia-3-no-more-damage-to-be-dealt-barclay-mills) your question.  You'll need to be patient until someone can see it and answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check the entire map, not just Barclay mills. Sometimes mission objectives for a particular district are located outside the district. For example for taking down the gun operations in Barclays you'll need to make a few trips to the bayou to break up some gun deals.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing else for barclay mills on the map, anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are other missions in Barclay Mills in the Bayou. Check your map for Bayou, you can't miss it.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the wire tap nodes and more objectives will show up on the map. They're also very small so you'll have to pay close attention and zoom in a little, otherwise they don't show up

Answer (score -3):

Same thing happened to me, I ended up finding a mission in another district that contributed to Barclay mill's damage. Hope this helps.

Comment: There are no more objectives on the map though.  Really, I searched everywhere.

Answer (score -3):

Go on the map, press "X" or whatever button it is for objectives (Check bottom right of screen) Hover over the objective that's missing (should be there) and Google it's name to find its location

Comment: Telling people to Google is very unhelpful.  That's exactly what Arqade is for.

Comment: When I press X and hover over the objectives the last one is "find and destroy.garbage barges"